# Asymptotic distribution of uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, chi-squared

**True or false? Explain your answer:**

If $X_1, ..., X_n\sim U(-1,1)$ are independent, then $$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2$$ is asmyptotic chi-squared distributed.

I try to solve the problem with the central limit theorem or the law of large numbers but i failed..

I calculated:
$ f_{X_i^2}(x)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} 1_{[0,1]} (x) $

$E(X_j^2)= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}} dx= 1/3 $

$E([X_j^2]^2)= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}} dx = 1/5$
 $\rightarrow Var(X_j^2)= \frac{1}{5} - (\frac{1}{3})^2= \frac{4}{45}$

So with the CLT:$ \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2 - \frac{1}{3} n}{ \sqrt{n} * \frac{4}{45}}= \frac{45}{4} [\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2 - \sqrt{n} \frac{1}{3}]$ converge weak to the standard normal distribution.

And on the other hand with the Law of large numbers: $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2 \rightarrow 1/3$ almost surely.

Comment: "If $X_1, ..., X_n\sim U(-1,1)$ are independent, then $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2$ is asmyptotic chi-squared distributed" No, $ \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j^2\to\frac13$ almost surely hence $ \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j^2$ is asymptotically a Dirac measure at $\frac13$. On the other hand, $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j^2-\frac13\sqrt{n}$ is asymptotically gaussian, yes, thanks to the most classical version of the CLT.

Comment: I delte my comments and add all to my first question. Means asymptotically distributed that it converge weak or almost surely against the distribution? Did you forget a factor $ \frac{45}{4}$ in the CLT?

Comment: Yes you copied correctly my indications so... no question left? ("Asymptotically distributed" means convergence in distribution, yes, and anyway I fail to understand what the option "almost surely against the distribution" would even mean.) (No, I forgot no factor in the CLT, the variance of the $X_i^2$ is necessary if one wants the limit to be *standard* normal, not only normal as my comment (rightfully) states.)

Comment: Okay, but then the statemant that $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2 \rightarrow 1/3$ is unnecessary for the exercise? I don´t understand why we are now finished the exercise.  I understand every step in your comment but not the full connection of it.

Comment: You lost me: the LLN shows that the statement in your post (convergence in distribution to some chi-squared distribution) does not hold since there is almost sure convergence to the deterministic limit $\frac13$, end of story.

Comment: So i don´t understand why your argued in comment one with the CLT? And  another question: when a random variable converge almost sure to a value, then it converge to the same value in distribution? So $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2 $ has as distribution a constant function with value $1/3$, but this can´t be true because a distribution function must converge to 1?

Comment: I did not argue, thank you, I just explained the two main results at hand in the situation (LLN and CLT). // Yes, if $Z_n\to Z$ almost surely then $Z_n\to Z$ in distribution. // "So ... has as distribution a constant function with value 1/3, but this can´t be true because a distribution function must converge to 1" Sorry but nearly nothing in this sentence is making any sense, so I suggest you grab a textbook on the subject...